# Prove or disprove: $t \mapsto \mathbb{P}( X_t \in A)$ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be an $\mathbb{R}$-valued stochastic process and let the law of $X_t$ be given by $\mathbb{P}_t$, $t \geq 0$. Let $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ be a Borel set. I am interested in the measurability of the following mapping
$$
[0, \infty ) \ni t \mapsto \mathbb{P} (X_t \in A) = \mathbb{E}[1_A(X_t)] \in [0, 1]. \tag{1}
$$
under the conditions stated below.

> Here is an example showing that this mapping is not measurable in general. Let $N \subset [0, \infty)$ be a set which is not Borel measurable, and let the random variables $X_t$, $t \geq 0$, be such that $\mathbb{P}(X_t =1)=1_N(t)$. Then clearly $t \mapsto \mathbb{P}(X_t = 1)$ is not measurable.

Now assume that:

> If $(t_n) \subset [0, \infty)$ is such that $t_n \rightarrow t_0 \in [0, \infty)$, then $\mathbb{P}_{t_n}$ converges weakly to $\mathbb{P}_{t_0}$. This means that for every continuous and bounded function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ we have
> $$
> \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \mathbb{P}_{t_n} (dx) = \mathbb{E} [f (X_{t_n})] \overset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \mathbb{P}_{t_0} (dx) = \mathbb{E} [f (X_{t_0})]
> $$
> The assertion is also true for bounded Lipschitz functions. Does this ensure the measurability?

Is it maybe possible to approximate the indicator function $x \mapsto 1_A(x)$ by suitable continuous functions which will imply the measurability? Alternatively, is it possible to obtain a right-continuous modification of $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ under these conditions? If so, this will ensure the joint measurability of $(t, \omega ) \mapsto X_t (\omega)$ and Tonelli's theorem will yield the measurability of the mapping in $(1)$.

---

If the answer is affirmative, it would be interesting to see if it also applies to the case where $X_t$, $t \geq 0$, are $S$-valued for a *sufficiently nice* metric space $S$.

Comment: You don't have to bring in continuity. It is measurable if $(X_t)$ is what is called  a measuarble process. See the definition on p.67 of this: https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1940-047-01/S0002-9947-1940-0000918-4/S0002-9947-1940-0000918-4.pdf

Comment: If we assume joint measurability of $X$ (i.e., measurability of $X$ as a function from $\Omega\times[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$, then $t\mapsto\mathbb{P}(X_t\in A)$ is indeed measurable. It can be proved by invoking the monotone class theorem.

Comment: I am aware that joint measurability combined with Tonelli's theorem would yield the assertion. However, I would like to find out if the conditions stated in the post are also sufficient. For example, is it possible to obtain a right-continuous modification of the process under these conditions? If so, this would ensure the joint measurability.

Comment: @SangchulLee : Remarkably I stumbled across your above comment (+1) the same day I read Kallenberg Lemma 1.26, the theorem and proof of which is essentially the same as your comment (i.e., they have a 3 line proof that basically says "extend by a monotone class argument").  =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is affirmative. Let $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ denote the set of all continuous and bounded functions on $\mathbb{R}$. Then the following claim holds:

> **Claim.** Let $(\mathbf{P}_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a collection of Borel probability measures such that
> $$ t \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi(x) \, \mathbf{P}_t(\mathrm{d}x) $$
> is measurable for each $\varphi \in C_b(\mathbb{R})$. Then the map
> $$t \mapsto \mathbf{P}_t(A)$$
> is measurable for every $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Indeed, for each open $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, there is a sequence $(\varphi_n) \subseteq C_b(\mathbb{R})$ such that $0 \leq \varphi_n \uparrow \mathbf{1}_U$ at every point of $\mathbb{R}$. So by the monotone convergence theorem,

$$ \mathbf{P}_t(U) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbf{1}_U(x) \, \mathbf{P}_t(\mathrm{d}x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi_n(x) \, \mathbf{P}_t(\mathrm{d}x). $$

Since the map $t \mapsto \mathbf{P}_t(U)$ is the pointwise limit of measurable functions $ t \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi_n(x) \, \mathbf{P}_t(\mathrm{d}x) $ as $n \to \infty$, it follows that the claim is true for open sets.

Moreover, it is clear that the collection of all Borel sets $A$ for which $t \mapsto \mathbf{P}_t(A)$ is measurable contains $\Omega$ and is closed under complements and disjoint countable unions (hence forms a Dynkin system). So by the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem, this collection contains all Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore the claim follows.

Comment: I do not agree with the end of your argument. The collection of all Borel sets $$ for which$t \mapsto _()$ is measurable is a monotone class not a $\sigma$-field in general. Yet, it is sufficient to conclude by the monotone class theorem since the collection of all closed set is closed under intersection and generates the Borel $\sigma$-filed.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan, I see, I think what I had in mind was that the collection of all such $A$ is closed under complements and "countably disjoint unions". This means that the collection is a Dynkin system (but not necessarily a $\sigma$-algebra).

Comment: It is clearly closed under disjoint countable unions and increasing countable unions. For an arbitrary countable unions $\bigcup_n A_n$, you cannot deduce the probability of the union only from the probability of each $A_n$.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan, Thank you for pointing out my mistake. I just realized, after writing up my first comment, that the collection need not be closed under mere countable unions.